# Java With Microsoft Access Database

Tags: java, asp.net, database, ms-access

I'm trying to use Ucanaccess library with java to connect to Microsoft Access ...

So i tried executing this code and it worked ....

```
        String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess:\\C:/Access.ACCDB";
        String query = "select * from [Donations]";
        try
        {   
        java.sql.Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(url, "","");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next())
        {

        System.out.println("Account No: " + rs.getString(1));
        System.out.println("Surname: " + rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println("First Name: " + rs.getString(3));
        }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
        while (ex!=null)
        {
        System.out.println ("SQL Exception: " + ex.getMessage ());
        ex = ex.getNextException();
        }
        }
        catch(java.lang.Exception ex)
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

let me explain what i'm trying to do

I have a Asp.Net website that uses Microsoft Access Database and in the same time i need a server (Java Application) to access the same Database (Microsoft Access) but when i uploaded the Database online to test if the server can get to the Database and modified the String for the connection ....

here is what it looked like

```
 String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://www.filetolink.com/download/?h=eaa4aab688d25e270539868d712961ab&t=1467140283&f=3ca9ad1869;";
            String query = "select * from [Donations]";
            try
            {   
            java.sql.Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(url, "","");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next())
            {

            System.out.println("Account No: " + rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println("Surname: " + rs.getString(2));
            System.out.println("First Name: " + rs.getString(3));
            }
            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            {
            while (ex!=null)
            {
            System.out.println ("SQL Exception: " + ex.getMessage ());
            ex = ex.getNextException();
            }
            }
            catch(java.lang.Exception ex)
            {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I tried running the code but I had an error message ... Here it is :

> SQL Exception: UCAExc:::3.0.6 given file does not exist:
>   http:\www.filetolink.com\download\?h=e6dc57e3485defa7c53e1c968a87fb1f&t=1467139906&f=3ca9ad1869

So What i'm asking for is :

1.How can I publish the website with the access database and let both of the Server and the website access the Database ?? (The server and the website aren't on the same Machine or computer .... )

2.if the answer to my question is that i can't ... then what can i do ?? other suggestions ? for having Database that can be accessed by a Remote Server (Java Application ) and A website (Asp.Net)

Answer (score 0):

MS Access is a desktop database not a server database management system. If  a program wants to access to such a database, the database file has to be on a local or network filesystem. So if your two applications are running on different machines in the same intranet, putting the database file on network filesystem would be a solution.

BUT: MS Access was never meant to be used as a web application's backend database. You should use a real server database like MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL or MySQL instead. Then your applications can access the database via network protocol. Theoretically it is possible to open the database port to the internet so that you can connect from everywhere. But this is not recommended due to security reasons.

So if your two applications aren't running in the same intranet it is better to create some webservices and let your other program call these webservices to get the needed information.